# P-adic integers and roots of unity

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Show that $\Bbb Z_p$ contains all the $(p-1)$th roots of unity.
For which primes $p$ does $\Bbb Z_p$ contains primitive fourth roots of unity?
Here $\Bbb Z_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers.
Proving that it has a $(p-1)$th root of unity is easy, but *all* roots is another matter.
Please help me with these questions.

I think for the second question, $p$ has to be $5$, but maybe there are other answers that I didn't think of.

*Edit*: I solved the first question, only need the second one. From what I can see, to be the primitive $4$th root, $4\mid(p-1)$, is that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: use [Hensel's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma). $\text{            }$

---

Added because you made an effort:

Second hint: what are the roots of $x^{p-1}-1$ in $\mathbf F_p$?

Third hint: for which $p$ does $x^2+1$ have a root in $\mathbf F_p$?

Comment: I tried to apply hensel's lemma but failed miserably, can you explain it to me a bit more?. Thanks

Comment: @user108680 Please improve your answer to include what you have, so that I can see where you are stuck. Thanks.

Comment: This is what i tried.Let f(x)=x^(n-1)-1,there exist x such that gcd(x,p)=1, just let x=1 and x^(n-1)=1 mod p.   
f'(1)=/=0 since it's still 1.
so there exist a solution in Zp that f(x)=0

Comment: ,And part 2, since with part 1, Zp has all (p-1)th root, it's obvious that if p=5, Zp had all 4th roots, one of them is a primitive root. But that answer is too stupid

Comment: In the previous comment,i meant f(x)=x^(p-1)-1

Comment: What does Fp mean? @Bruno Joyal

Comment: i Solved the first question, only need the second one. From what i can see, to be the primitive 4th root, 4|(p-1), is that right?